# App Center push works in Postman but not my C# application

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, visual-studio-app-center

I have a service in my C# application which uses App Center's api to push notifications. All my request come back with 401s (Unauthorised) yet, when I used the **same** details on postman i.e. *content*, *header auth*, *owner_name* and *app_name* it works successfully and sends the application.

This is very confusing and I am wondering if Postman handles some extra bits and pieces which I am missing out.

#### C# Push Notification Service

```
private async Task<bool> PostHttpRequest(PushNotificationModel pushNotificationModel)
{
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-API-Token", _appCenterApiToken);
    var url = "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/myowner/myapp/push/notifications";
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pushNotificationModel);
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, byteContent);
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

I debugged this code and used the same data being passed to the client to use on Postman, hence why `Model` data is absent for example.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put the code below in your startup form.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: I put that code in the first line of the method above. It still returns a `401` :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue using Telerik Fiddler. This helpful tool allows you to actively view HTTP traffic to and from your machine. Now the mistake was a silly one on my part but it boiled down to changing this:

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-API-Token", _appCenterApiToken);`

to:

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Token", _appCenterApiToken);`

As the first one was actually appearing in the `HTTP` header as `Authorization : X-API-Token apiToken` rather than `X-API-Token : apiToken` it caused the request to be bad, hence returning `401 (Unauthorised)`